# jquery set pieces on dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to set pieces on jquery dialog. here is my code but its not work :(

```
$("#main_menu").dialog(
{
    dialogClass: 'transparent',
    autoOpen: true,
    show: "explode",
    hide: "explode",        
    pieces: 16,
    resizable: false,
    width: 522,
    hight: 522
});
$(".blue-pill").click(function()
{
    close_all();
    $("#main_menu").dialog("open");
    return false;
});
```

can anyone tell me whats wrong in this code ? 
any help appreciated ?
thanks

Comment: what do you mean by pieces ?

Comment: In jQuery UI dialog document `pieces` is not a valid option. Can you explain if its an user defined variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use code like the following.

```
hide: { effect: "explode", pieces: 16, duration: 10 },
```

Answer (score 1):

pieces should be a part of `hide` and `show`

```
hide: { effect: 'explode', pieces: 16 }
show: { effect: 'explode', pieces: 16 }
```

`autoOpen` should be `false` if you are opening it from any event.

make sure that `$("#main_menu")` returns a valid div and `length > 0`

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("#div1").dialog({

        autoOpen: false,
        width: 500,
        show: "blind",
        hide: { effect: "explode", pieces: 16, duration: 2000 },

        modal: true,
        height: 'auto',
    });

});
function f1() {
    $("#div1").dialog("open")
}
```